# Laravel 5: Download PDF and Word documents get error after downloaded

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, download, ms-word

I use below code to download the files (my file can be .pdf or Ms word). After downloading any of the files, the file is error and can't be opened / view.

```
$file= "uploads/files/heng_kaknika.docx";
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf', 'Content-Type: application/msword',);
return response()->download($file, 'new_name.docx', $headers);
```

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: It could be that path not found. Why not open the downloaded file in plain text editor to see what's inside? Is it binary, or with errors?

Comment: Which error you are facing?

Comment: The file is found in the path. Which plain text editor do you recommend? When I open the downloaded file in Sublime editor, it is binary. How to fix this?

Comment: In the file, I see these: 504b 0304 1400 0600 0800 0000 2100 f021
ec7d 8e01 0000 1306 0000 1300 0802 5b43
6f6e 7465 6e74 5f54 7970 6573 5d2e 786d
6c20 a204 0228 a000 0200 0000 0000 0000.......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, remove header from `download()` and check it. As L5 work without header. See [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses)

```
$file= "uploads/files/heng_kaknika.docx";
return response()->download($file, 'new_name.docx');
```

Comment: With or without $header, It is fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you!